# Does anyone know what this transaction refers to, and if funds can be retrieved?

Tags: ether, etherscan, hardforks, replay-attack

Hello Ethereum community!

I was looking back at transactions made with an old ethereum wallet and came across the following.

[image]

Does anybody know what this refers to?
I am not sure what this "ReplaySafeSplit" contract was and where this Eth may be. I believe it refers to the time when ETH and ETC split (hard fork), but these eth appear **only** as a transaction **out** of the wallet.
(this is web link of the transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5e12337a97a6442ce7c9b1d169094091bb33704bf20f6c856ff9b35770287e7b)

Could anybody confirm whether these Ether amounts could actually be retrieved?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://medium.com/@timonrapp/how-to-deal-with-the-ethereum-replay-attack-3fd44074a6d8

Answer (score 0):

Reddit will be able to help you here.
Splitting is not needed anymore due to technical update of protocolls. Latest eth-wallets only send eth, latest etc-wallets only send etc.

Goodluck